# Is it possible to use a spell scroll with a spell that requires a bonus action to cast?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, actions

The DMG contains *spell scrolls* (on page 200), with the following rule:

> If the spell is on your class's spell list, you can use an action to read the scroll and cast its spell without having to provide any of the spell's components.

This is all well and good for spells with a casting time of 1 action (which admittedly is most of them), but for spells with a bonus action casting time, how is it supposed to work?

Does it require:

- Both an action and a bonus action?
- Just an action?
- Just a bonus action?
- Something else I haven't thought of?

In case it needs saying, I'm not interested in speculation here - only RAW-based answers or explicit statements of developer intent should apply.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [errata](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DMG_Errata.pdf) to the DMG included a modification to spell scrolls, which replaces the sentence given in the question with:

> Casting the spell by reading the scroll requires
>   the spell’s normal casting time.

So a spell scroll that holds a spell with a casting time of one bonus action now requires a bonus action to cast, resolving the contradiction.